# Linq order by property, then by original order

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Suppose I have `var lst = List<Foobar>` that I populated in loop. I cannot modify the `Foobar` object.

What would be the best way to effectively do an `OrderBy` on one property in an `IEnumerable`, but preserve the original order in case they are equal? For example, if I had this:

```
var lst = new List<Foobar> {
new Foobar{Foo = "b", Bar=3},
new Foobar{Foo = "b", Bar=1},
new Foobar{Foo = "a", Bar=2}
}
```

I would want to ensure I'd get back the following after `lst.OrderByWithPreserveOrder(x => x.Foo).ToList`:

```
List<Foobar> {
new Foobar{Foo = "a", Bar=2}
new Foobar{Foo = "b", Bar=3},
new Foobar{Foo = "b", Bar=1},
}
```

Comment: How about posting an example?

Comment: Now, why don't you try it with a simple `OrderBy`? It will return the result you expect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The implementation of `OrderBy` is already a stable sort, which is to say that it will maintain the original ordering in the event that objects are equal.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* `OrderBy` was not a stable sort, this is one way I could think of doing it with a single LINQ statement:

```
list.Select((element, index) => new { Element = element,
                                      Index = index})
    .OrderBy(a => a.Element.Foo)
    .ThenBy(a => a.Index)
    .Select(a => a.Element);
```

Comment: `Assuming OrderBy was not a stable sort`, don't make wrong assumptions.

Comment: @L.B Thanks Captain Obvious, you must be great at parties.

Comment: @test I must admit, you are good in solving problems that don't exist